# Корзина покупателя Django

Tags: django

возникла проблема с добавлением товаров в корзину. Товары в корзину не добавляются, после добавление прилетает HTTP/1.1/ 302 0
Подскажите как можно исправить эту проблему
Код: https://github.com/LeonardoBigShot/django-shop

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь что слишком мало информации, но посмотрев github можно сказать что у вас не хватает cart.urls, на которое идет ссылка с основного приложения

И само приложение cart не имеет джанго моделей